# How to assign values to a const structure pointer's variable?

Tags: c, pointers, structure, constants

In the below piece of code, I am not able to change the values of x and y individually. Can some one help me with assigning these values individually?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct p
{  
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main()
{   
    int p2 = 55;
    int p3 = 99;
    //const struct p *ptr1 = {&p2,&p3};  --- giving the expected result
    const struct p *ptr1;
    ptr1->x = &p2;  //error
    ptr1->y = &p3;  //error
    printf("%d %d \n", ptr1->x, ptr1->y);
}
```

*Note: I have searched for such an example, I could not able to find and I am running out of time. If the question is already asked, I am really very sorry to waste your time and please provide me the link for the same to refer.*

Comment: The address of `p2` and `p3` seem to get cast to an integer value? What *is* the expected result?

Comment: So the problem is, when you try to dereference a `const`, `unallocated` pointer for writing compiler does not perform implicit cast from `int *` to `int` and write it silently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two important issues to consider:

1. `const struct p*` is a "pointer to `const p`", which means you cannot modify the instance it points to. It can point to a non-`const` object, but you can't use the pointer to modify said object.
2. A pointer must point to a valid object before it can be de-referenced.

You need to create a valid `p` instance, then make the pointer point to it:

```
struct p x = {p2, p3};
const struct p *ptr1 = &x;
```

In this example, a `p` instance is created in automatic storage. You can also instantiate one dynamically using `malloc` if that suits your needs better. For example,

```
struct p *px = malloc(sizeof (struct p));
px->x = p2;
px->y = p3;
const struct p *ptr1 = px;
```

In both examples, you can modify the instance `ptr1` points to via `x` and `px` respectively, but not via `ptr1`.

Comment: I need to change only some of the structure values, not for the whole structure

Comment: @Denise You can do that via `x` or `px`. Note that `ptr1` doesn't allow modifications to the object it points to.

Answer (score 5):

Since the author seemed to want to change a struct that she was declaring const, this might in fact be a very relevant answer.

A common gotcha directly related to this question is that

```
const struct p *ptr1
```

is a pointer to a "const struct p", which means the pointer variable ptr1 can change and point to a different struct p later, but regardless of where it points, you can't write to members of the struct using that pointer (e.g. `ptr1->x = blah;`).

What some might be looking for is a pointer which is const, and thus can't ever point to a different piece of memory, after being assigned one at its initialization.

That would be

```
struct p * const ptr2 = ptr1   // whatever ptr1 currently points to, ptr2 will point to there, from now to forever (for the lifetime / scope of ptr2).
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const struct p *ptr1 = {&p2,&p3}; //  --- giving the expected result
```

It compiles, but with this warning; and either way, it probably doesn't do what you want anyway:

> warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'const struct p *' with an expression of type 'int *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

To create a constant pointer to struct, you could use this:

```
const struct p *ptr1 = &(struct p){p2, p3};
```

Quick note about [lifetime](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.5.2.5.html#1065):

> If the compound literal occurs outside the body of a function, the object has static storage duration; otherwise, it has automatic storage duration associated with the enclosing block.

Comment: Does the lifetime of the rvalue on the RHS get extended?

Comment: What is the life of temp object?

Comment: @Ja͢ck Either the lifetime of the temporary gets extended, in which case you should mention it in your answer, or it doesn't, in which case the code is illegal. I was asking a genuine question, in case this is one of the places where C differs from C++. In the latter, the code would be illegal.

Comment: @juanchopanza I've included a passage of the standard that should apply here; the lifetime here *should* be automatic within `main()`. Of course, I could be wrong .. :)

Comment: @Ja͢ck That seems right. So it does look like a C differs from C++ here. I'll remove some of my previous comments.